# command line find instances of substring in file split by carriage return only

Tags: command-line

I have a file that logs the verbose output of an ffmpeg encoding, including any errors.  However, each "line" is indicated only by a CR (0x0D), instead of a CRLF.  FINDSTR apparently doesn't think that CR indicates a new line, so I basically have a single monolithic string.  I need to count how many instances there are of the substring "aresample" in the log file, but even if there are fifty of them, since they are in a single "line", it only returns 1.  What can I do to count multiple instances of a substring in a single "line"?  Using Windows.

Comment: `powershell -Command get-content File_cr.txt ^| out-file File_crLF.txt` but _powershell_ tends to write output file as UTF-16LE with BOM so you could add `-Encoding` parameter e.g. `-Encoding default` for "_ANSI_" output.

Comment: thank you!  This works great.  I had to add the Encoding bit like you said, because otherwise it added a null character (0x00) between EVERY character (basically doubled the file size and made it unsearchable)